# Máscara em valores da tabela

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Estou procurando uma forma de criar "Máscaras" para os valores da minha tabela em ASP.NET. Atualmente, estou exibindo os valores assim:

```
@model TB_RESUMO_GERAL
List<TB_RESUMO_GERAL> rg = (List<TB_RESUMO_GERAL>)ViewData["relatorioGeral"];
    .
    .
    .
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>Mês</th>
            <th>Val. Esperado</th>
            <th>Val. Adquirido</th>
            <th>Recebimento Mês</th>
            <th>Atraso</th>
            <th>Amortização</th>
            <th>Selic</th>
            <th>Premio selic</th>
            <th>Taxa Gestão</th>
            <th>Seguro</th>
            <th>Despesas</th>
            <th>Não identificados</th>
            <th>Valor Disponível</th>
            <th>Contratos Ativos</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (TB_RESUMO_GERAL resumo in rg)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@resumo.DT_MES_UTILIZACAO</td>
                <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.VL_ESPERADO</td>
                <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.VL_DISPONIVEL</td>
                <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.VL_RECEBIMENTO_MES</td>
                <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.VL_ATRASO</td>
                <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.VL_AMORTIZACAO</td>
                <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.VL_SELIC</td>
                <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.VL_PREMIO_SELIC</td>
                <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.VL_TAXA_GESTAO</td>
                <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.VL_SEGURO</td>
                <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.VL_DESPESAS</td>
                <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.VL_NAO_IDENTIFICADO</td>
                <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.VL_DISPONIVEL</td>
                <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.QTD_CONTRATOS_ATIVOS</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

E os valores estão saindo assim:

[image: Dados exibidos]

Gostaria de colocar pontos para milhares e virgulas para centavos, além de tirar esse horário da data. Ex (R$ 1.245,50) (02/2016).

Comment: no seu projeto você tem jquery.mask.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você está usando o c#, o que eu usaria no seu caso para não precisar usar outra biblioteca JS seria:

Para os valores de dinheiro, transformaria em double e aplicaria o Currency do `String.Format("{0:C}",100) //sendo 100 = valor que você transformou em Double`.

Para data basta converter em string passando o formato que você deseja, lembrando que precisa ser um `DateTime`, tipo `Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");`
Veja os exemplo no link abaixo:

[Exemplo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MB2VxW)

Lembrando que a moeda do Currency esta relacionada a cultura do seu servidor ou sessão. No exemplo está $USD porque o servidor é americano, acredito que no seu PC estará R$

Answer (score 3):

Bom eu estou utilizando esse plugin https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/ onde você abre o arquivo src => jquery.mask.js e importa para o seu projeto e faz a devida referencia.

na sua view:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.mask.js"></script`>

```
     @model TB_RESUMO_GERAL
    List<TB_RESUMO_GERAL> rg = (List<TB_RESUMO_GERAL>)ViewData["relatorioGeral"];
        .
        .
        .
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>Mês</th>
                <th>Val. Esperado</th>
                <th>Val. Adquirido</th>
                <th>Recebimento Mês</th>
                <th>Atraso</th>
                <th>Amortização</th>
                <th>Selic</th>
                <th>Premio selic</th>
                <th>Taxa Gestão</th>
                <th>Seguro</th>
                <th>Despesas</th>
                <th>Não identificados</th>
                <th>Valor Disponível</th>
                <th>Contratos Ativos</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (TB_RESUMO_GERAL resumo in rg)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><span class ="date">@resumo.DT_MES_UTILIZACAO</td>
                    <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.VL_ESPERADO</td>
                    <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.VL_DISPONIVEL</td>
                    <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.VL_RECEBIMENTO_MES</td>
                    <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.VL_ATRASO</td>
                    <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.VL_AMORTIZACAO</td>
                    <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.VL_SELIC</td>
                    <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.VL_PREMIO_SELIC</td>
                    <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.VL_TAXA_GESTAO</td>
                    <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.VL_SEGURO</td>
                    <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.VL_DESPESAS</td>
                    <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.VL_NAO_IDENTIFICADO</td>
                    <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.VL_DISPONIVEL</td>
                    <td><span class="money" /> @resumo.QTD_CONTRATOS_ATIVOS</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->


$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".data").mask("99/99/9999");
   $(".money").mask("R$###.###.###,##");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Agradeço a ajuda de todos! Tive problemas para usar `String.Format("{0:C}", ValorDinheiro)`, então fiz um método para montar minha máscara. Espero que ajude outros:

```
public static string FormataDinheiro(string dinheiro) {
        string retorno = ""; int diferença = 2; int length = dinheiro.Length;

        if(length > 2){
            if(length < 6){
                retorno = dinheiro.Substring(0, length - diferença) + "," + dinheiro.Substring(length - diferença, 2);
                diferença = length;
            }else{
                retorno = "," + dinheiro.Substring(length - diferença, 2);
            }
        }
        while((length - diferença) > 0){
            if(diferença + 3 < length){
                diferença += 3;
                retorno = "." + dinheiro.Substring(length - diferença, 3) + retorno;
            }
            else{
                retorno = dinheiro.Substring(0, length - diferença) + retorno;
                diferença = length;
            }
        }
        return retorno;
    }
```

Quanto a data, usei `String DataComMascara = Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` conforme a dica do Leonardo Bonetti e funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: Lembrando que isso acontece no seu servidor.